# What is $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{a}x^n\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials

I just want to know what is $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{a}x^n \,dx.$$ It looks to be around $8.78770602605$ after some brute force, but how do you get to the answer? It could be the integral of the polynomial of $x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x^2+x^1$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for pointers on formatting your questions, and I also suggest you take a look at the community guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: This can help you [Harmonic Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) this will answer you for sure but I would suggest you can read more on [Polylogarithmic Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) too

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Due to the linearity of the integral, it results that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{a}x^{n}\right)\mathrm{d}x & = \sum_{n=1}^{a}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{a}\frac{1}{n+1}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{a+1} 
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?